# How do I close all Connections on my idHTTPServer?

Tags: delphi, indy

Having idHTTPServer and want it to stop receiveing requests. What is the right way of doing this ?

I am not sure in my code below

```
function TRPSystem.CloseAllConnections: boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
  l: TList;
  c: TIdThreadSafeObjectList;

begin
  Result := false;
  c := Main.Server.Contexts;
  if c = nil then
    Exit();

  l := c.LockList();

  try
    for i := 0 to  l.Count - 1 do
      TIdContext(l.Items[i]).Connection.Disconnect(False);
    Result := true;
  finally
    c.UnlockList;
  end;
end;

procedure TRPSystem.ServerStop;
begin
  CloseAllConnections();
  Main.Server.Scheduler.ActiveYarns.Clear; 
  Main.Server.IsActive := false;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

To fully deactivate the server, you need to only set the server's `Active` property to False. That stops the server from listening for new connections AND closes down any currently active connections. There is no need to close client connections manually, or clear the active Yarns list. The `Active` setter handles everything for you:

```
procedure TRPSystem.ServerStop;
begin
  Main.Server.Active := false;
end;
```

Otherwise, if you do not want to fully deactivate the server, just take it offline temporarily, you can reject new HTTP requests as they arrive by using the `OnHeadersAvailable` and `OnHeadersBlocked` events.  Return False from `OnHeadersAvailable`, and then return a suitable status code from `OnHeadersBlocked`, such as 
`503 Service Unavailable` (the default is `403 Forbidden`), eg:

```
procedure TMain.ServerHeadersAvailable(AContext: TIdContext; const AUri: string; AHeaders: TIdHeaderList; var VContinueProcessing: Boolean);
begin
  if Offline then
    VContinueProcessing := False;
end;

procedure TMain.ServerHeadersBlocked(AContext: TIdContext; AHeaders: TIdHeaderList; var VResponseNo: Integer; var VResponseText, VContentText: String);
begin
  VResponseNo := 503;
end;
```

Comment: hm.... honestly speaking you've got my point, i just wanted to add Stop and Start methods to my API without stopping windows process or service, offline mode - would be the great decision, but unfortunately my knowledge of Indy wasn't enough to solve this task, could you give a small example how would i do my server offline and online back without killing the process ?

Comment: hm... looks like i know how would i do that, will test my idea

Comment: Also i wanted to ask - what will be with memory ? Lets say i have a long task for 5-10 mins, with lots of created objects, if i say Server.Active := false will i get memory leaks, so, do i have to do additional memory cleaning ?